# Creating 2 arrays from a text file

Tags: c#, arrays, file-io

I have a huge text file (33 mb, encoded as Unicode with the FSO as "TristateTrue")) that I want to put into two different C# arrays.

The lines in the text file are formed like this:

```
 40 TAB 10 TAB 15 TAB 7 TAB 8
 65 TAB 2  TAB 9  TAB 3 TAB 6
 30 TAB 89 TAB 11 TAB 5 TAB 14
```

The **first** C# array should then read this:

```
 int[] outputs=new int[iLineCount+1];    
 outputs[0] = 40;
 outputs[1] = 65;
 outputs[2] = 30;
```

and the **other** C# array should read like this:

```
 int[][] inputs = new int[3][];
 inputs[0] = new int[5];
 inputs[1] = new int[5];
 inputs[2] = new int[5];

 inputs[0][0] = 10;
 inputs[0][1] = 15;
 inputs[0][2] = 7;
 inputs[0][3] = 8;

 inputs[1][0] = 2;
 inputs[1][1] = 9;
 inputs[1][2] = 3;
 inputs[1][3] = 6;

 inputs[2][0] = 89;
 inputs[2][1] = 11;
 inputs[2][2] = 5;
 inputs[2][3] = 14;
```

I feel that this is really difficult. 
If anybody can help, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you very much!

**NOTE**: The TAB represents a tabulator character, and the lines are "separated" by a NewLine character

Comment: That's not so hard. I can't believe you have no starting point. Please try to solve this yourself and come back when you have a concrete problem. BTW: Question titles should not contain tags here on SO.

Comment: Yes, my best vote would be using a FileReader but then trouble begins. If I knew how to do it, I would not ask here.

Comment: You need to show some effort. What trouble begins when using `FileReader`?

Comment: Is this code that is called often, or is it once-in-a-while code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to get you going:

```
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("filename", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                while (streamReader.Peek() > -1)
                {
                    string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                    string[] parts = line.Split('\t');

                    outputs[lineCounter] = int.Parse(parts[0]);

                    inputs[lineCounter] = new int[4];
                    inputs[lineCounter][0] = int.Parse(parts[1]);
                    inputs[lineCounter][1] = int.Parse(parts[2]);
                    inputs[lineCounter][2] = int.Parse(parts[3]);
                    inputs[lineCounter][3] = int.Parse(parts[4]);

                    lineCounter++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Remember that this code does not catch exceptions or checks for valid data. I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me how to declare my 2 arrays? I thought I could simply declare them like this             int[][] inputs = new int[][];
            int[] outputs = new int[]; but I guess C# wants me to tell it the size of it already when I declare them.

Comment: Yes, that's why I left them out. You have to know up front how many lines you will store. So you have to open the file twice (once for counting the lines, once for reading the data). I would personally write a short class with 5 properties storing the data and you can store these in a `List<myClass>` object for easier access.

Comment: If you are not bound to arrays, you can be lazy and use a list<int>. You do not need to declare the length.
As a drawback, lists tend to consume more memory then an array.

Since you seem to know how long a line ist, `string[] parts` wont be a problem and can stay an array for that part.

If you need it, you can create an array with fixed length afterwards with
`yourlist.ToArray() `

Answer (score 2):

Look at the methods [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) and [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx).
Together, they should give you a pretty good starting point.